# Change status bar color in android api level 15

Tags: android, statusbar

i used this library:
`compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'`

```
private void initStatusBar() {
        Window window = getWindow();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            tintManager.setTintColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorBlack));
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
```

This method is called in main `activity` before `setContentView()`. It's working but the status bar content items are all white, so nothing seen, I want black color status bar content text.
My min sdk version is 15 and max 26. My background is a `png` file. so I want the same in status bar.

Comment: you can use default statusbar instead library

Comment: i dinrt understand what u said, can u please explain

Comment: do not use compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'